# Is this object casts or array casts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I know that：

```
console.log({}.length);
> undefined

console.log([].length);
> 0

console.log([] + {});
> [object Object]
```

but,why `([] + {})` is `[object Object]`

```
console.log(([] + {}).length);
> 15
```

**Why...I can't figure out**

Answer (score 1):

My console gives me this:

```
typeof []
"object"
typeof {}
"object"
typeof [] + {}
"object[object Object]"
typeof ([] + {})
"string"
```

The length of your last console.log is because it is a string.